# Allow access without authentication

Tags: nginx

192.168.1.1 visits 192.168.1.0 (server) and has to do nothing,

192.168.1.2 visits 192.168.1.0 and has to enter an user and a password,

192.168.1.3 visits 192.168.1.0 and will get a "403 Forbidden" warning.

I only managed to bring twice at the same time working, but never three.

Can you help me?

TIA

Comment: What about any other IP address? Is the third case the default?

Comment: Yep, exactly! One IP should access it without any requests, another one should access it with an auth and everyone else should be denied.

Answer (score 0):

The first two cases can be achieved using the `satisfy` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#satisfy) for details.

The 403 response can be generated separately, using a `geo` block and an `if...return` statement. See this document for details.

For example:

```
geo $reject {
    default        1;
    192.168.1.1    0;
    192.168.1.2    0;
}
server {
    ...
    if ($reject) { return 403; }

    satisfy any;
    allow 192.168.1.1;
    deny  all;

    auth_basic           "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have to mention that I use Ubuntu and this looks like Windows.

Comment: Actually it’s Nginx, because that’s the tag you used for your question.

Comment: Hello, sorry for asking again, but WHERE do I have to put this? I installed nginx-full and found geoip.conf and geoip2.conf, but it seems not logical to put it in there. These files only have one line and it says "load modules".